# How to hide admin users from django admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

By default django admin shows all users on the admin site. I am working on a app where client wants to show only that users which are registered from mobile or web, not admin users. How to apply query on django admin site for this? Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
def queryset(self, request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        return User.objects.all()
    return User.objects.filter(is_superuser=False)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(your_filter)
```

you can change the `queryset` in the `admin.py` of that model where you want to change the display

Answer (score 3):

You can override ModelAdmin's [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method for this:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.filter(is_superuser=False)
        return qs

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```